# Why do my actor tests fail non-deterministically?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, java-threads, akka-testkit

I'm using Akka 2.4.2 with TestKit and Scalatest for writing and testing actors. It looks like there is a race condition whenever I'm inspecting some mutable state encapsulated by my actor. I have a really simple actor that saves some state in a remote database:

```
class MyActor(dao: MyDao) extends Actor {
  var state: String = ""
  def receive = {
    case Set(str) => 
      state = str
      dao.save(state)
  }
}
```

The DAO method has the type signature `dao.save(s:String): Future[String]`. The call to the database is asynchronous and is made after setting `state = str`, so nothing would appear to be blocking the assignment of this string. The actor is accompanied by a unit test:

```
it should "set mutable state" in {
  val ref = TestActorRef(new MyActor(new MockDao))
  ref ! Set("foo")
  ref.underlyingActor.state shouldBe "foo"
}
```

If I run this test individually it will pass reliably. However, when I run all my actor tests (I have a dozen different actors), this test case will pass/fail non-deterministically. So there appears to be some kind of race occurring. I'm using the default Akka configurations. Any thoughts from the Akka community on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Should you be inspecting the private state of the actor? Why not assert externally visible behaviour (such as that your `MockDao.save` gets called with the proper parameter).

Comment: Also, isn't there a race condition? I thought messages are delivered asynchonously, so doesn't it take some time before the state can be checked?

Comment: Doesn't `TestActorRef` execute messages synchronously? see: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#Synchronous_Unit_Testing_with_TestActorRef

Comment: Is `dao` relevant? If you remove `dao.save(state)`, does the problem persist? I'm wondering if the test might be failing as a result of the actor crashing.

Comment: @nmurthy: True, the `TestActorRef` dispatches synchronously. I guess that's a reason not to use it...